# wpa_cli "could not connect to wpa_supplicant"

Tags: server, 20.04, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to set up Wifi on an Ubuntu Server 20.04 system. I've messed around a bit with networking stuff on this machine already, in ways I can't quite remember (with `netplan` and `wpa_supplicant`), so I can't quite guarantee things are in a fresh state. However, when I try to run `wpa_cli`, I get:

```
Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: (nil) - re-trying
```

After that, it just hangs.

I've tried specifying the interface with `-i` and specifying the `wpa_supplicant` socket with `-p`, nothing works. Actually, for the latter, I don't know where the socket is. There's nothing in the usual places like `/run` or `/var/run`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found the answer [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wpa_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_cli). It's a bit tedious. Thanks to marceloneil, reference unix.stackexchange.com, question #382527.